# Granting Access to custom page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-security

I have a custom sharepoint page that inherits from a custom dll I created
the page is located inside my shared documents library.

I managed the page's permissions so that there are two groups who can access it: one with a Full control level and the other with Contribute level.

the problem is that any member from the second group (with Contribute security level) tries to access the page, the unauthorized login page appears and the user cannot browse the page.

while any user from the first group (with Full Control) level can access the page normally.

so is there something missing that make custom pages only accessible by Full Control Users ? and is there any thing that can be done in the code to fix this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you have written some code in this page that can not be performed with contribute permission level. So please try to access this page after commenting all the code you wrote in this page or create a new page with out any code. If you could access it with contribute permission level please use impersonation in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help
I created a page with no code and cou;d access it with contribute permission.
I really have no idea about the code that cannot execute with contribute permission. I have some code that deals with security permissions for some lists, could it be the reason
thanks

Comment: Yes you are right
I commented the code that deals with the security permissions and it worked, so I guess I'll use impersonation.
thanks